# Draw Canvas Line on Image

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have to do a simple task in my WPF application. Its based on drawing lines on a Canvas Control. The code works fine until I'am truing to add a Image to this canvas control, and truing to the same think on it.

Lets look to the code:

```
void loadImage()
{
    Image image = new Image();

    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ofd = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    {
        Filter = @"Images|*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.gif"
    };
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
        BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
        src.BeginInit();
        src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        src.UriSource = new Uri(fileInfo.FullName, UriKind.Relative);
        src.EndInit();
        image.Source = src;
        image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

        CanvasE.Children.Add(image); <- Canvas object with my image

        int zindex = CanvasE.Children.Count;
        Panel.SetZIndex(image, zindex);
        Canvas.SetLeft(image, 50);
        Canvas.SetTop(image, 50);
    }
}
```

And the code with Events on my Canvas Control, that respond on drawing.

```
private void CanvasE_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
}

private void CanvasE_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        Line line = new Line();

        line.Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
        line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
        line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
        line.X2 = e.GetPosition(this).X;
        line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(this).Y;

        currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

        CanvasE.Children.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Now the problem.
As described above, if we adding the image to Canvas Control in that form, the drawing are note shown. I thick the problem is in layering the Children Object.

**How to do that drawing to future saving the image and drawled line?**

Comment: You want your **Image** to be _behind_ all of the lines, so don't bother setting its `ZIndex` property (or set it to zero). Then set the ZIndex of your line elements (eg. `Panel.SetZIndex(line, 1);`) so that they appear on top.

Comment: omg, that sow dump from my implementation. You are right ! Thk you.